# Uploading files in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

I'm trying to upload a file with Laravel but it does not work

I will send the field with the meta name `view`

```
  <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="tab-content">
                                    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab1success">
                                        <form  method="post"  name="type"  action="songs">
                                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="Name">نام موزیک</label>
                                                <div class="col-md-7">
                                                    <div class="input-group">
                                                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                                                            <i class="fa fa-music">
                                                            </i>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <input id="Name" name="title" type="text"
                                                               placeholder="نام موزیک" class="form-control input-md">
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                            </div>
                                            <br>
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="Name (Full name)">دسته
                                                    بندی</label>
                                                <div class="col-md-7">
                                                    <div class="input-group">
                                                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                                                            <i class="fa fa-list">
                                                            </i>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <select id="Name" name="category" type="دسته بندی"
                                                                placeholder="دسته بندی" class="form-control input-md">
                                                            <option>fun</option>
                                                            <option>love</option>
                                                            <option>birth</option>
                                                            <option>wedding</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                            </div>
                                            <br>
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="Name (Full name)">توضیحات</label>
                                                <div class="col-md-7">
                                                    <div class="input-group">
                                                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                                                            <i class="fa fa-file-text-o">
                                                            </i>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <textarea id="Name" name="text" placeholder="توضیحات"
                                                                  class="form-control input-md"></textarea>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <br>
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="Name (Full name)">انتخاب
                                                    فایل</label>
                                                <div class="col-md-7">
                                                    <div class="input-group">
                                                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                                                            <i class="fa fa-folder-o">
                                                            </i>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <input id="meta" name="meta" type="file"  placeholder="انتخاب فایل"
                                                               class="form-control input-md">
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <br>
                                            <div class="row" style="text-align: center">

                                                <div class="col-md-10 " style="text-align: center">
                                                    <button id="Name" name="submit" type="submit" placeholder="انتخاب فایل"
                                                            class="form-control input-md" style="text-align: center">اضافه
                                                    </button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Controller

```
 public function create(Request $req, $type) {
        $this->authorize('is_admin');
    $req->file('meta')->store('app');
      // $path = Storage::putFile('app', $req->file('meta'))
    }
```

**error**

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
>   Call to a member function store() on null

Here is an [image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EMNy.png)

Does anybody know what i should do about this?

Answer (score 0):

Add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your `<form>` tag in your blade:

```
<form  method="post"  name="type"  action="songs" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Based on your blade file you can see that the file `meta` being uploaded is not required, so in your controller, you need to check if the file was sent before calling the `store` method on it. Check this:

```
public function create(Request $req, $type) {
   $this->authorize('is_admin');
   $file = $req->file('meta') ? $req->file('meta')->store('app') : null;
}
```

Comment: Great. That was a pleasure to help you.

Comment: Mark the answer to close the question